# Vaadin JPAContainer SQLContainer BeanItemContainer

Tags: jpa, persistence, containers, vaadin

I am a newbie to Java Persistance and Vaadin. I have been desperately trying to figure out how to use the SQLContainer and I have somewhat succeeded.

I have also succeeded in using 
    BeanItem item = new BeanItem(new RegisterBean())
and
    email.addValidator(new BeanValidator(RegisterBean.class, "email"));

to hold the data from my `fieldGroup` and validate the data.

However, I have no clue why and how I should be using the JPAContainer for Java Persistance. 
I have desperately searched for resources that would shed some light but, there seems to be not a lot of tutorials or discussion about the JPAContainer and its use in Vaadin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From https://vaadin.com/add-ons/jpacontainer

> Vaadin JPAContainer connects Vaadin UI components with persistent data
>   objects. You can use JPAContainer to display data in a table, tree, or
>   any other selection component. By placing a JPAContainer into an
>   editable Table you have created a working CRUD component with minimal
>   effort.

You can use/access the entities beans directly as data model.

Usage scenario is: Direct access to the JPA. If you haven't another DTO or DAO layer.

Comment: Yes you are right. But, my question here is then, can you not connect a table directly to a SQLContainer which would essentially do the same thing would it not?

Comment: Not exactly. Changes to the entity is managed, thus is automatically persisted by the application server. Using SQLContainer means, that you are using this addon directly to modify the database table via JDBC. It has several disadvantages, like no connection pooling (takes time to connect and disconnect). Basically both are using SQL to modify the data. The main difference is, that one JDBC resource is managed and the other isn't. JPA provides more complex operations like cascading for relationships. A seamless integration for Java EE 6. Besides SQLContainer isn't supported in V7 nor will be.

Comment: SQLContainer can be used outside an Java EE server environment. It wraps and offers only a layer for direct database operations. Without, you would simply use beans and use the data for the JDBC/SQL operation.

Comment: What do you mean by SqlContainer won't be supported in Vaadin7. If I understand correctly, the addon is no longer supported but its built into the Vaadin core library now. I am using SqlContainer with Vaadin 7. can you please clarify.

Comment: Yes. You understand that right, that the support for the **addon** is suspended. SQLContainer has been integrated into Vaadin 6.7 and this add-on will not receive any further updates. All changes will be made to the Vaadin Framework only. I only want to point that out, because I cited from the add-on page. You can still use it in V7. I clarify my comment above.

Comment: To clarify: By "You can still use it in V7." cinhtau meant that [SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.html) continues to be bundled as a core part of Vaadin 7 as well as 6.7 and 6.8. The *add-on* should be used only with Vaadin 6.6 and earlier, not 7 or 6.7/6.8. In contrast, the JPAContainer continues as an add-on (not bundled with Vaadin) but has new versions that work with Vaadin 7.1 and other versions for Vaadin 6.